# How to zoom using Alt+mouse wheel without highlighting shortcut letters?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts, zoom

There is this very helpful zoom shortcut in Photoshop: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd>.

But it has a very bad side effect: because it uses <kbd>ALT</kbd> the shortcut letters of the menus get highlighted (e.g. **F** for File, **E** for Edit, **I** for Image). Making the selection of the next tool impossible.

If I zoom using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd> and then try to hit <kbd>E</kbd> to use the eraser, in fact I will open the Edit menu. So before pressing <kbd>E</kbd> I need to press <kbd>ALT</kbd> again. Which is very annoying.

I just noticed that if I use the right <kbd>ALT</kbd> key the problem don't happen. But using the right one is kind of unpractical.

How to go around this issue while still using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd> for zooming in/out quickly?

Comment: Are you on Mac? I'm on Windows and I know the problem, but here it only seems to happen if I don't actually use the mouse wheel. The Shortcut letters get highlighted when I hit `Alt` and disappears again when I use the mouse wheel.

Comment: I'm on windows. It happens as soon as I hit Alt, no matter if I use or not the wheel. Also the shortcuts never get un-highlighted when I let Alt go, no matter I use or not the wheel. This happens since ever on Windows XP, 7, 10, Photoshop Cs6 and others I used before.

Comment: Strange. I'm using CC 2019 right now. I don't have the problem in Photoshop, but I do have it in InDesign.

Comment: Your version is brand new, maybe this was fixed in later versions. Mine is CS6

Comment: Yes maybe, but it still exists in InDesign so I don't know. Could be system related ...

Comment: Hmm . . . might just be that old version. This seems to be fixed in Photoshop CC versions on Windows 10 at least.

Comment: Never used Alt+wheel. After setting in preferences, I just use wheel to zoom in/out, no need to add Alt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you go to Preferences > Tools > checkbox "Zoom with mouse wheel". No <kbd>ALT</kbd>, just keep on rollin'.

Comment: I never use the wheel to scroll the canvas anyway, so I won't miss it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it might be an issue with your particular configuration, so [resetting your preferences](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/preferences.html) may solve the problem

If that doesn't help, you should seek help in the [Adobe support forums](https://community.adobe.com/), though your comments note that you are using CS6, which I believe is no longer being supported by Adobe so you might be out of luck on that front.

In the meantime, a workaround would be to tap the escape key when you're done zooming. This should deselect the toolbar.

Comment: Yes, Alt again or Escape revert the problem at the cost of another key hit. I never remember to hit Alt again because it's so counter intuitive. I use the brush all the time and I always hit Alt to pick a color and never need to hit it again.